# Limit after flatMap not terminate sequence

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why this produces one "1" and then is not terminating but going to infinite loop of no results?

```
Stream.of("x")
      .flatMap(_x -> Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1))
      .limit(1)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Can you formulate differently, that's unclear what you ask

Comment: because the `flatMap` will iterate all elements of the inner stream. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45039630/7607923

Comment: Try putting the limit on the inner stream, i.e. `Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(1)`